# php should not send email multiple times to same person who reply multiple time with same email

Tags: php, mysql

I am New to php . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My issue is that when user reply to any post with specific id, php sends an email alerting involved users that have previously comment on the post with same id, the problem is if the person has entered 3 reply for that post the user gets 3 emails, Since my database has reply entries from the same user with email for each post multiple times.

This is what is the problem

$to = $row['Email'];

How do I make sure it does not send an email to the user multiple times?

```
// update data in mysql database 
$sql4= "select * from answer WHERE id='$id'"; 

$result4=mysql_query($sql4);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
{

$to = $row[‘email’] ;   

// Your subject
$subject="$name Reply on example.com”;

// From
$header="from: Associate <no-reply@example.com>";

// Your message

$message = "$name Reply on example.com\n$comment\nDate and Time=$datetime\nhttps://www.example.com/upload/$img\nfor More Visit https://www.example.com/visit/“;

// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}
```

Comment: If this is production code, you really should escape your inputs, and once you're more comfortable with PHP, replace the mysql() functions with PDO :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to this: `$sql4= "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM answer WHERE id='$id'";`

Answer (score 0):

you can add email in array and use array_unique function so your duplicate entry will remove auto.

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red");
print_r(array_unique($a));
?>
```